# Console Resolution program not accurate

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application

Okay so I'm having some issues with a program I'm writing. I want to be able to display the exact resolution of the console window when I run my program. Whilst my program is running, if I manually move one of the edges of the window to make it smaller/bigger, I want the resolution to update. At the moment, I'm nearly there, but I'm having some problems.

In the code below, first I'm setting where I want the console to start on the screen (*at x100, y100*), then I'm trying to use `r.right` and `r.bottom` to track the resolution, and I set new values, where `r.right = 700`, and `r.bottom = 400`, but when I run my program:

- Instead, `r.right` seems to have a value of **1249** when I run my program, then if I exit and run again, it'll have a value of **1119**? Same with `r.bottom`, it'll have a value of **775**, and then of **645**.
- When I simply MOVE the window, these same values also update, which I don't want them to, as the resolution isn't even changing.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main() {

HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
RECT r;

int counter = 0;


GetWindowRect(console, &r);

//                  pos(x)  pos(y)     width    height 
MoveWindow(console, 100, 100, r.right, r.bottom, TRUE);

r.right = 700;
r.bottom = 400;

while (1) {

    GetWindowRect(console, &r);

    std::cout << "Loops: " << counter << '\n';
    std::cout << "Resolution (x): " << r.right << '\n';
    std::cout << "Resolution (y): " << r.bottom << '\n';
    std::cout << "Position (x): " << r.left << '\n';
    std::cout << "Position (y): " << r.top << '\n';

    std::cout << "---------" << '\n';
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));

    ++counter;
}

}
```

I feel like I'm using this `r` values incorrectly, Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: "resolution" has very little to do with r.bottom/right, those variables merely tell you where the bottom/right corner of the window is located.  The width of the window is r.right - r.left.  Type Alt+Space while the console window is displayed > Properties > Layout tab.  You don't care much for the "Let system position window" checkbox.

Comment: Oh gosh, I didn't notice this, thank you Hans!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
std::cout << "Resolution (x): " << r.right - r.left << '\n';
std::cout << "Resolution (y): " << r.bottom - r.top << '\n';
```

Also, indenting your code would be good.

Comment: Hi @paulsaunders, this seems to be working, I tried doing something like this previously but I think I can the calculation wrong, thank you!

Comment: Try `MoveWindow(console, r.left, r.top, 700, 400, TRUE);`

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment as I literally have just done this, thank you so much!